# How to pass a googleMapController to custom widget? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, scaffold, action-button

On my flutter googleMap i have quickDialButton, which has multiple buttons. One of them is supposed to center the camera of the parent mapWidget which happens via the googleMapControllet that i am passing as a parameter.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(42, 23), zoom: 11.5),
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        mapToolbarEnabled: false,
        onMapCreated: (controller) {
          googleMapController = controller;
        },
        markers: customMarkers.toSet(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: MyQuickDialButton(
        c: googleMapController,
        latitude: userLocation.latitude,
        longitude: userLocation.longitude,
      ),
```

The problem is that the googleMapController gets initialized after the floatingActionButton property to the scaffold. How can i update it after i have the controller initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing this controller, i created new function that can run controller methods from the parent widget.

```
void _centerCamera() {
      googleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude),
              zoom: 16)));
    }

...
floatingActionButton: MyQuickDialButton(
        c: _centerCamera,
        latitude: userLocation.latitude,
        longitude: userLocation.longitude,
      )
```

and later i am calling just the function "c" from the child widget